# why do i get "User Exists" twice when logging development output to bash with tail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I moved the mailer call in my User model to a custom Devise controller, and suddenly no longer get emails in development. SMTP is all set up in config and working correctly (I know because it works when the mailer call is in the User model as an `:after_create` - which incidentally, won't work in production).

So I ran `tail -f log/development.log`, hit submit to see if there's a routing conflict caused by my Devise extension, and found this in the output of my #create action

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-07-03 14:48:06 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blahblah", "user"=>{"email"=>"j@q.com", "firstname"=>"i", "lastname"=>"i", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'j@q.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'j@q.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "firstname", "lastname", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "j@q.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$8YxM8UHDnwS8lcxhiE6Gn.VAbLo8bE8HggCQVuIPl8XYXaevHt8F."], ["firstname", "i"], ["lastname", "i"], ["created_at", "2016-07-03 21:48:06.899722"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-03 21:48:06.899722"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Looks like my Devise extensions isn't even being used?

Here's the #create action

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    if @user.save
        UserMailer.new_user(@user).deliver_now
        #AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(@admin).deliver_now
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
 private
    def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :approved)
    end
end
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, if: -> { self.email.present? }
  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true

  def active_for_authentication? 
    super && approved? 
  end 

  def inactive_message 
    if !approved? 
      :not_approved 
    else 
      super # Use whatever other message 
    end 
  end
end
```

And then my route is `devise_for :users, :controller => { registrations: 'registrations'}`

So I guess it's a two part question:

1. Is the double `User Exists` indicative of anything?
2. What is wrong with my setup? I've followed the official Rail's docs to the T.

Comment: just to add a bit more context, could you add your `user` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your devise routing config to:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}
```

And in your user validation, I think you should remove the `if` option

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

I think that should fix it. Why? Because uniqueness would first check that the record exists in the db, then the `if` option would also do the same. Not totally sure if my thought is right, but I think that should be the problem.

Let me know if I was able to help.

**PS:** There's a known Rails bug which also emits your SQL statements to the logs twice, I think it's being fixed or there's a pending PR for it, this is caused by setting a different logger in your Rails application. I don't think yours is related to this, because of the variance in time taken for your SQL statements to be executed.

Comment: It was the `controller:` over `controllers:` in the router.

Comment: You're welcome! How about the `User Exists` being logged twice?

Comment: That still occurs. I found out that it logs once when it checks `presence` and again when it checks `uniqueness`. There's only one SQL insert, so turns out that part of the question isn't really a problem.